# how to remove parent if child has specific text?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to remove the parent div if the child has specific text:

```
<div>
  <span>test</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

In the above code I want to remove the div which contains the **test**. I tried a lot 
something with filter function,but thinking fully wrong concept. So what is the best way to remove this?

So, how to detect the text is tested or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has) with [contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) - used contains since you said contains - if you want to check for exact match then you can't use it

```
$('div').has('span:contains(test)').remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7a3F6/)

---

For exact match

```
$('div span').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'test';
}).parent().remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3qBu4/)

Comment: So, what to use for exact match?

Comment: I'd edit your question to describe exactly what you want - "contains" or "exact", as there is already a deleted answer which does "exact"

Comment: @MilindAnantwar although I have just run the code and it throws an exception. You should look at that before undeleting ;-)

Comment: @andyb:is OP looking for exact?? i answered by seeing "child has specific text:" and deleted by seeing  "contains" from OPs question

Comment: @MilindAnantwar yes the question is not clear. Either way, your answer still throws an exception for me. Anyway, Arun has already provided an accepted answer! Here's a `+1` for spamming your inbox with a slightly off-topic conversation Arun :D

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, the error is `$(this).parent().remove();` - it shouled be `parent()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if it's empty or not, then use:

```
$("span:not(:empty)").parent().remove();
```

If more specific when you want to check whether your span contain `text` string or not then you can use `has()` along with `:contains()` selector:

```
$('div').has('span:contains(text)').remove()
```

or:

```
$('span:contains(test)').closest('div').remove();
```

Comment: OP is looking for `div` which contains `test`

Comment: _remove the parent div if the child has specific text_ @karna OP stated this on top line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('span:contains(test)').closest('div').remove();
```